# Eager load and store Singleton

Tags: c#, design-patterns, initialization, singleton, static-constructor

As part of trying to propose an answer to another question, I wanted to create a `Dictionary` of self-registering Singleton instances.   Specifically, something like this:

```
public abstract class Role
{
    public static Dictionary<string, Role> Roles = new Dictionary<string, Role>(); 

    protected Role()
    {
        _roles.Add(this.Name, this);
    }
    public abstract string Name { get; }
}

public class AdminRole : Role
{
    public static readonly AdminRole Instance = new AdminRole();
    public override string Name { get { return "Admin"; } }
}
```

However, the `AdminRole` constructor isn't being called unless I access `Instance`, so it's not being added to the `Roles` dictionary.  I know I could just instantiate the dictionary using `{ AdminRole.Instance.Name, Admin Role}`, but I'd like adding new roles to not require the `Role` class to change.

Any suggestions?  Is this even a good design for accessing Singletons by string?

---

The line of code to test the result is:

```
var role = Role.Roles["Admin"];
```

It's successful if you don't get a `KeyNotFound` exception (or `null`).

There *can* be an explicit initialization of `Role` (such as `Role.Initialize()`), but not of the subclasses - the idea is to be able to add a subclass so the dictionary has it, without ever needing to change anything pre-existing.

Comment: The reason why you don't want change `Dictionary` in `Role` - you don't want make changes with each new subtype or you don't want make changes ever?

Comment: @nsinreal - The former.  I want to be able to create a new `Role` type without doing anything more than subclassing it.

Comment: Okay, understand. Reflection

Comment: @nsinreal - The original asker doesn't want to have to "scan the whole assembly for `IRole`s".  I'm good with Reflection, provided that it's entirely self-contained in `Role`.

Comment: what problem asker got with that? We can scan whole assembly for inheritors of Role, there no need in interface. One problem with static dictionary initalization that I see - if you load another assemblies at runtime you can't work with them

Comment: @nsinreal - What if `Role` is extended in a different assembly?  I'm not going to worry about runtime loading - I'll let the original OP worry about that.

Comment: there is another way. You can pull out `Name` from `Role` class and make it works by convention naming. You replace your dictionary by your method `GetInstance(key)` or by your proxy class. After call of GetInstance you firstly checks on your dictionary. If there no such role, you iterating over all assemblies loaded to programm, using GetType(key + "Role") and working with that.

Comment: @nsinreal - Hmm. If I follow that right, it could work.  Put it into an answer and I'll give it a try and an upvote, at the least.

Comment: I'm sorry about delay, but hm.. that's more harder then I think. Isn't that better - to wrote method `RegisterRoles(assembly)` and use it after loading of each assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm.. There is real problem, that user can create his AppDomains. There are no good way to get all loaded AppDomains in current process. I use bad hack founded in network: [Hot to get list of all AppDomains inside current process?](http://miteshsureja.blogspot.com/2012/02/hot-to-get-list-of-all-appdomains.html). Result code:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(Role.GetRole("Admin").Ololo);
}

public static class AppDomainExtensions {
    public static List<AppDomain> GetAllAppDomains() {
        List<AppDomain> appDomains = new List<AppDomain>();

        IntPtr handle = IntPtr.Zero;
        ICorRuntimeHost host = (ICorRuntimeHost)(new CorRuntimeHost());
        try
        {
            host.EnumDomains(out handle);
            while (true)
            {
                object domain;
                host.NextDomain(handle, out domain);
                if (domain == null)
                    break;
                appDomains.Add((AppDomain)domain);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            host.CloseEnum(handle);
        }

        return appDomains;
    }

    [ComImport]
    [Guid("CB2F6723-AB3A-11d2-9C40-00C04FA30A3E")]
    private class CorRuntimeHost// : ICorRuntimeHost
    {
    }

    [Guid("CB2F6722-AB3A-11D2-9C40-00C04FA30A3E")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    private interface ICorRuntimeHost
    {
        void CreateLogicalThreadState ();
        void DeleteLogicalThreadState ();
        void SwitchInLogicalThreadState ();
        void SwitchOutLogicalThreadState ();
        void LocksHeldByLogicalThread ();
        void MapFile ();
        void GetConfiguration ();
        void Start ();
        void Stop ();
        void CreateDomain ();
        void GetDefaultDomain ();
        void EnumDomains (out IntPtr enumHandle);
        void NextDomain (IntPtr enumHandle, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)]out object appDomain);
        void CloseEnum (IntPtr enumHandle);
        void CreateDomainEx ();
        void CreateDomainSetup ();
        void CreateEvidence ();
        void UnloadDomain ();
        void CurrentDomain ();
    }   
}

public abstract class Role
{
    private static Dictionary<string, Role> Roles = new Dictionary<string, Role>(); 

    public static Role GetRole(string key) {
        if (Roles.ContainsKey(key))
            return Roles[key];

        foreach (var appDomain in AppDomainExtensions.GetAllAppDomains()) {
            foreach (var assembly in appDomain.GetAssemblies()) {
                var type = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.Name == key + "Role").FirstOrDefault();// (key + "Role", false, true);              

                if (type == null || !typeof(Role).IsAssignableFrom(type))
                    continue;

                Role role = null;

                {
                    var fieldInfo = type.GetField("Instance", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);


                    if (fieldInfo != null) {
                        role = fieldInfo.GetValue(null) as Role;               
                    }
                    else {
                        var propertyInfo = type.GetProperty("Instance", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

                        if (propertyInfo != null)
                            role = propertyInfo.GetValue(null, null) as Role;
                    }
                }

                if (role == null)
                    continue;

                Roles[key] = role;

                return role;
            }           
        }

        throw new KeyNotFoundException();
    }

    public string Ololo {get;set;}
}

public class AdminRole : Role
{
    public static readonly AdminRole Instance = new AdminRole();

    private AdminRole() {
        Ololo = "a";
    }

}
```

What we do: we iterate over all AppDomains, getting from them all Assemblies. For each Assembly we try to find type `Key + "Role"` (convention based), checking that there are no problems, get "Instance" field.

Now, about hack: it's bad idea. Better, if you will create singleton with list of all loaded domains. On creating of domain you must add it to list, on unloading - remove from list and remove all types that belongs to domain from Roles and another classes. How it works now: there are no possibility to unload AppDomain, because there always is a link on one of it's types. If you don't need to unload AppDomains, you can leave this code as it wrotten.

If you never will create AppDomain, you can iterate only throught `AppDomain.CurrentDomain` assemblies.

Comment: Wow.  That's rather impressive.  I don't think I'm going to provide an answer to [the other question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/204550/how-can-i-improve-this-design-so-that-i-dont-need-to-dynamically-scan-classes-a) if this is what it's going to take to make it work, but I'll certainly link him here.

Comment: @Bobson and that's really ugly. There are some problems with Mono and another stuff like LinqPad. And that's not officially suported feature, so hell knows what can happen. Try to think about creating of static method `FindRoles(assembly)`

Comment: @Bobson If there can be a lot of subsingletons (at least two) you can make some static class AppDomainHelper with LoadDomain() and UnloadDomain() and events DomainLoaded, DomainBeforeUnload. I hope you understand what to do next. Questions?